# SpringBoot automatically converts integer to boolean with @RequestBody annotation? How can I reject the integer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

My request was an `application/json` type like this: `{"able": true}`, but when I send the request like this `{"able":12345}`, the field `able` still can get a correct value `true`. Why?

```java
@PatchMapping("/{id}/path/{name}")
public ResponseEntity someMethod(
    @Valid @RequestBody SomeRequest request) {
    // do something
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeRequest {
    @AssertTrue
    @NotNull
    private Boolean able;
}
```

Comment: The reason must caused by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, how to fix it... It can converter Integer to Boolean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because jackson.databind will parse int to bool when field type is bool.
Find code in `NumberDeserializers.BooleanDeserializer`

```
            JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();
            if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
            if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE) {
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
            return _parseBoolean(p, ctxt);
```

`_parseBoolean(p, ctxt)` will parse int to bool.

We can do it by ourselves not use default.

1. Create our bool deser class.

```java
public class MyDeser extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();
        if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        return null; 
        // not parse int to bool but null and it may work ok.
        // if throw new IOException(), it will work fail. Maybe return null means use other deser to deal it. throw Exception means fail. I don't know it clearly.
    }
}
```

2. Create a configuration and inject a SimpleModule bean. I write in application

```java
 @SpringBootApplication
 @Configuration
 public class DemoApplication {
     @Bean
     public SimpleModule addDeser() {
         return new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Boolean.class, new MyDeser());
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works! Awesome! But I didn't use this one. Thank you first~ Good answer! My answer is refactoring the setter method of class `SomeRequest ` and give it a method `setAble` like this: `public void setAble(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            submitted = (Boolean) value;
        }
        if ("true".equals(value)) {
            submitted = true;
        }
    }`. Because I don't want to affect other methods which are using  Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer posted by [sunsunsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12544350/sunsunsun)
is exactly. It works well. But my answer is re-code the setter method of `SomeRequest` like this:

```java
    public void setAble(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            submitted = (Boolean) value;
        }
        if ("true".equals(value)) {
            submitted = true;
        }
    }
```

Because Jackson is using the setter method to inject value.

### And then I can just accept the value which is true or "true". And I don't want to affect others.

Answer (score 2):

create a Custom BooleanDeserializer by extending the JsonDeserializer from jackson library,

```
public class BooleanValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    try {
        return jsonParser.getBooleanValue();
    }catch(JsonParseException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s is not a valid Boolean value for %s", jsonParser.getText(), jsonParser.getCurrentName()));
    }
}
}
```

and add the following annotation on the Request Object for Deserialization

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeRequest {
    @NotNull
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BooleanValueDeserializer.class)
    private Boolean able;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because each non-zero integer value is true? What happens if you sent `{"able":0}` ?

Comment: #### It's false. And like -12345 or 423 and other integers are true

Comment: so that is an answer) As I said Java treats each non-zero integer value as true.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I have no ideas to reject the Integer value. It seems that others didn't meet the same problem because I can't search out the answer by google...

Answer (score 0):

Each non zero value will be treated as true in boolean case. If you send zero then it will set value to false.

Comment: It is. But how to reject the integer value. I'm doing a validation, it couldn't accept the request send an incorrect value, must be a boolean value.

Comment: If you only want to consider true or false as valid values. You can write custom validation check. Just accept value with String and compare value as true or false. If yes then do your work, otherwise thrown an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Jackson's Coercion Configuration

https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-4-5-cbc91c00bcd2